# Sqlite3 performance issues with single row UPDATE

Tags: c++, linux, performance, sqlite

**Background:**

So as the title suggests, I am having performance issues with sqlite3 doing a simple update on a single row, and I can't track it down.

I've already disabled synchronous and journal_mode, as suggested in every other performance thread I've read through.

---

**Details:**

Kernel: Linux beaglebone 4.4.30-ti-r64

FileSystem: Linux beaglebone 4.4.30-ti-r64

SQLite: 3.8.7.1 2014-10-29 13:59:56

Row Count: 163

Query: (UPDATE tableX SET value='15' WHERE parm='parmY')

Time To Execute: 2730 ms

Schema: TABLE tableX (rowId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, parm varchar(32), value varchar(32));

---

I make the assumption that I'm only updating one row, and there's only 163 to parse through to find the proper one, so where am I going wrong to cause this type of performance hit on such a simply query?

I initially thought it was my code causing the issue somehow, but when I tried it directly through the terminal, the time was very similar.

---

**Edit 1:** Copied DB to host PC, and it is performing as expected with very quick return from this query. Now to figure out exactly what's going on with the target system that could be causing this.

Comment: C++ code, table structure

Comment: Code is irrelevant, as it happens in terminal... will add table structure though

Comment: I would try to rule out the current system. Copy the database to a pc and try the same query.

Comment: Wow, great idea, can't begin to understand why my brain didn't go there. It is indeed <1s on my actual PC. So there's something off about the target system that's slowing it down.

Comment: Either @drescherjm or OP, in my opinion either of you could make a nice answer, to create a decent Q/A pair.

Comment: I am not sure my comment solves the issue just gets the OP to look elsewhere.

Comment: Show the table structure, any indexes you have, and the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).